# Word to describe a drunk

Tags: synonyms

I have heard a word which sounds something like 'kallied', 'kylied' or similar used to  to describe a person in drunken state. eg.

> Fred had been drinking all night and was completely *(word that sounds like 'kallied')*.

Searching on these spellings does not turn up any useful results online.

Is this a word which anyone recognises, and what would the correct spelling be?

Comment: I'm sure someone somewhere will have "verbified" ***caleigh / cèilidh / céilí*** (a traditional Scottish or Irish social gathering) - but given the problems with spelling, I doubt it would catch on.

Comment: I've seen "walleyed" used (in various spellings)

Comment: @HotLicks: Indeed. I even found various spellings [within the same sentence:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wanted+to+get+wall-eyed%22) *If a man wanted to get **wall-eyed,** by golly, he got **walleyed** and the citizenry lined Hollywood Boulevard in cheering thousands as he rolled home in a colorful if not pious manner.*

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed such a word. 
[Kaylied](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kaylied)

> adjective
>   British *slang* intoxicated; drunk

‘Kali’ also spelled ‘Kayli’ (pronounced *Kay-lie*) is a north of England term for a sherbet-like confectionary with a [texture more like granulated sugar.](https://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Food-and-Drink/Question262595.html)  Apparently it is known as ‘[Rainbow Crystals](http://selectionfox.com/?product=rainbow-crystals-kayli)’ these days.

In the same way that ‘sherbet’ is sometimes expanded to mean an alcoholic drink and someone who has overindulged may be said to have ‘had too many sherbets’, a person may be said to be kaylied.